# Combine a result file from several txt-files

Tags: python, bash, awk

I need to create a summary file from a large portion of txt-files from different folders. I started to do it with python, but any provided solution is fine ie. python, awk, bash

```
find = "find -name \"summary.txt\" > output.txt"
os.system(find)

o = open("output.txt", "r")
read = o.readlines()
for items in read:
    pilko = items.split("/")
    id = pilko[1]
```

I need to search summary-files from subfolders and compile the results of the txt-file to a result file. I'm kinda stuck here how to open the txt-file in for loop, save the data to a result file and move on.

```
plate = pilko[4]
print id+"/"+pilko[2]+"/"+pilko[3]+"/"+plate+"/"+pilko[5]
foo = open("id+"/"+pilko[2]+"/"+pilko[3]+"/"+plate+"/"+pilko[5]", "r")
```

That is approach that I tried, but everything is failing there:)

I could imagine there are easier ways to do this that I haven't heard yet.

Comment: `id` is a builtin method. never use it as a variable

Comment: post some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in `find -name 'summary.txt' -print` ; do cat $f >> /tmp/grandsummary.txt ; done
```

Comment: Could go even simpler: `cat $(find . -name 'summary.txt') > grandsummary.txt`. If too many arguments, `find . -name 'summary.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 cat > grandsummary.txt`. Or with recursive blobbing, `cat **/summary.txt > grandsummary.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code coloration, your quoting is incorrect in the last line. Furthermore, you should probably use the os.path APIs for your stuff. And `with` just in case to ensure the file is correctly closed. Finally, no need to `readline`, a file is an iterable of lines. Finally, why do you recompose your path manually? Why not just `open(items, 'rb')`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a python solution:

```
import os
with open('/path/to/result/file.txt', 'wb') as result_file:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/path/to/start/directory'):  # walk the file system
        if 'file_name_I_want.txt' in files:  # This folder has the file i'm looking for!
            with open(os.path.join(root, 'file_name_I_want.txt'), 'rb') as src_file:  # open it up
                result_file.write(src_file.read())  # Read from src, store in dest.
```

This was written from memory, so it may need some jiggering.